# I want to understand syntax used pic24 eds

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic24

```
__eds__ WORD __ramspace[0x100] __attribute__((eds,address(0x8000ul),noload));
```

I want to understand the syntax above ( The program is for pic24 and in C ) especially `__ramspace[0x100]`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is your compiler?

Answer (score 4):

*It's a bit late, but maybe this can help someone else:*

**__eds__** means you want to put whatever follows into the extended data space. You do this when you want to use the data space beyond a certain address. You can find from which address the extended space begins for your MCU in the datasheet.

**WORD** means you will reserve whole words (and not for instance bytes). For a pic24 this means 16 bit chunks.

**__ramspace[0x100]** is a 1D array 256 in size. When you take a look at what is written in front of this, you can see you are declaring an array named **__ramspace** , size **256 words** (so 256x 16 bit values) in **extended data space** (**eds**).

Now you must declare the offset e.g. the start address of the array (the physical address where __ramspace[0] - first array element - will be). This is what **0x8000** does.

Finally you instruct the compiler if the array should be initialised at boot-up (for instance filled with zeros). In your case there is a **noload**, meaning random data will be inside the array at boot-up, until you write your own values in it.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`__ramspace[0x100]` is the only part of that line which is just pure C. :) It declares an array of `0x100` (256, in decimal) elements of type `WORD`. The name of the array is `__ramspace`.

- See [@Brian Cain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/489590/brian-cain)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26609393/28169) for details about `eds`.
- The `address(0x8000ul)` argument to `__attribute__()` presumably makes the linker put the variable in question at location `0x8000`.

Answer (score 0):

The `__eds__` qualifier is described in the "[MPLAB® C Compiler for PIC24 MCUs and dsPIC® DSCs User’s Guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51284H.pdf)" as:

> In the attribute context the eds, for extended data space, attribute
>   indicates to the com- piler that the variable will may be allocated
>   anywhere within data memory. Variables with this attribute will likely
>   also need the **eds** type qualifier (see Chapter
>   6. “Additional C Pointer Types”) in order for the compiler to properly generate the correct access sequence. Note that the **eds** qualifier
>   and the eds attribute are closely related, but not identical. On some
>   devices, eds may need to be specified when allocating variables into
>   certain memory spaces such as space(ymemory) or space(dma) as this
>   memory may only exist in the extended data space.

`__ramspace` is not a special designator, it's just the identifier that was chosen.